# Regular Expression in C#.net for alphabets and optional hypen

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression in .NET for validating words with alphabets and option hyphen,
no other special characters or numbers is not allowed

e.g

```
ASAS-JDS
ANND-Jdsd
asdasda
```

I got the regular expression for alphabets

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

but i also need the optional hyphen "-" to be included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either put in the '-' character at the beginning or end of the character class `[-a-zA-Z]` or `[a-zA-Z-]` (when appearing as the first or last character, it's not recognized as part of a character range) or put it in there in escaped form, outside the character ranges (e.g. `[a-z\-A-Z]`).

(Note that, in the latter case, unless you use a @-prefixed string, you will need to escape the escape character itself. I.e. either `@"[a-z\-A-Z]"` or `"[a-z\\-A-Z]"`).

Comment: The - can be put at the beginning without escaping (or at the end, as you suggested) http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html "Both [-x] and [x-] match an x or a hyphen."

Comment: @xanatos Correct, thanks for pointing this omission out in the reply, I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: the final regular expression ^[a-z\\-A-Z]+$  works perfectly. Thanks Cumbayah